# SQL Like query with reverse name return result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my sql table,

```
id |     name     | city
------------------------
1  |   John Due   | New york
2  |  Luke Wright | Kingston upon Hull
```

In my search inbox, If I search "Upon Kingston Hull" return second row or if I search "Due John" then return first row.

then how can i write like query ?
and also write query in Laravel Eloquent

Comment: that is good to see you as asking question on SO.but please post your efforts. stackoverflow is a learning platform. it is not for solving an individual user problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a long term need for this requirement, you might want to look into [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).  Short of this, MySQL offers a `REGEXP` operator which can do some fairly complex regex searching.  To search the `name` column for both `Due` and `John` we can try:

```
SELECT id, name, city
FROM yourTable
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]' AND name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Due[[:>:]]';
```

To search for `Due` *or* `John`, then we can use an alternation:

```
SELECT id, name, city
FROM yourTable
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]](John|Due)[[:>:]]';
```